# Puppet ENC choose environment based on a fact?

Tags: puppet

I have an ENC setup which determines which environment a node will be placed during check-in.

*Currently I'm keeping track of node types using the host name in an external database.*

When a node checks in for the first time I'd like to determine the environment it should be in based on a fact. For example say I want to use the `OS` fact to determine if a new node should be sent a windows or linux configuration file.

It seems I only have access to the nodes host name, which I could potentially send to PuppetDB to retrieve the facts, but this wouldn't be the case on the initial check-in of a new node being registered with the Puppet Server.

Does anyone have a practical solution for this?

Comment: For info, if you want to use the OS fact to decide what config file should be sent that doesn't need the environment to be set.  You can just have a manifest which changes behaviour or the template used according to the `os` fact.  Obviously that's not answering the question, but I thought it's worth mentioning :)
(Yes this is from long ago, but I just stumbled upon it when looking for something else about ENCs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I directly access PuppetDB from my ENC, even on the very first check in I could access all the facts for my node.

Here is an example ENC using a [python library for PuppetDb](https://github.com/voxpupuli/pypuppetdb) use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from pypuppetdb import connect

db = connect(host='puppetdb', port=8080, ssl_verify=False, ssl_key=None, ssl_cert=None, timeout=20)

certname = sys.argv[1]

try:
  node = db.node(certname)
  print 'environment: ' + node.fact('os').value
except:
  print 'environment: default'
```

Comment: As long as it occurs post-pluginsync and pre-catalog compilation. You are placing this script on the Puppet Master in the directory for the ENC?

Comment: It is the script I have specified for my enc in the `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet` folder. I guess the facts are uploaded before it runs.